# Por qué no se muestra la barra de navegación del segundo activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, navigation, graph

Estoy utilizando Navigation Component, actualmente tengo dos grafos, el primero tiene un activity que muestra la pantalla de login y la de registro, y de la pantalla de login navego a un segundo grafo con otro activity que contiene una barra de navegación. El problema que tengo es que cuando navego desde el grafo A al grafo B, es como que solamente me muestra el contenido de lo que tendría el fragment cargado del grafo B, pero no muestra la barra de navegación:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_home"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.ludiras.ameisin.ui.home.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >

        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment2_to_profileFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment2" />

    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment2"
        android:name="com.ludiras.ameisin.ui.profile.view.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
    
</navigation>
```

Este es el método que uso para navegar al segundo grafo:

```kotlin
private fun setupObservers() {
        viewModel.getEmailRegisterLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToHomeNavGraph()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        })
    }
```

Y en el primer grafo tengo, además del include con dicho grafo, esta acción que es la que me permite la navegación:

```xml
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.ludiras.ameisin.ui.login.view.LoginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionLoginFragmentToHomeNavGraph"
            app:destination="@id/nav_graph_home" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionLoginFragmentToRegisterFragment"
            app:destination="@id/registerFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />

    </fragment>
```

La otra solución que había pensado era implementar solo un activity con solamente con grafo e ir mostrando y ocultando la barra donde la necesito, pero quiero saber si de la forma que lo estoy haciendo con dos grafos es posible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explicación

Tu error es creer que cada graph está asociado a una activity diferente, siendo que en realidad no existe ninguna relación entre ellos. Cuando navegas al `homeFragment`, todavía estás en la primera activity y por eso no se muestra el contenido de la segunda.

Las activities tienen un `NavHost` que está asociado a un `NavController`. Podemos decir que cada activity tiene un navController (en realidad tiene uno por cada navHost). Ahora el `NavGraph` que usa este controller es algo dinámico. Inicialmente es el definido en el atributo `app:navGraph` de su host asociado pero si quieres puedes cambiarlo en cualquier momento con el método `navController.setGraph(R.id.otherGraph)`. A su vez, un mismo graph puede ser usado por varios controllers al mismo tiempo, o por ninguno.

### Solución

Si quieres navegar a otra activity, debes agregarla a tu graph y tratarla como una destination más.

```
<activity
    android:id="@+id/home_activity"
    android:name="com.ludiras.ameisin.ui.HomeActivity"
    android:label="Home"
    tools:layout="@layout/activity_home" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="com.ludiras.ameisin.ui.login.view.LoginFragment"
    android:label="fragment_login"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/actionLoginFragmentToHomeActivity"
        app:destination="@id/home_activity" />

</fragment>
```

```
val action = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToHomeActivity()
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

Pero debes saber el navController no puede cerrar activities, por lo que deberás encargarte de eso manualmente.

### Solución recomendada

La solución recomendada es la última que comentaste: tener un único activity  y mostrar u ocultar la barra de navegación según corresponda. Lo cuál puedes hacer con el método `addOnDestinationChangedListener`

```
// MainActivity
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    when (destination.id) {
        R.id.loginFragment, R.id.registerFragment -> // ocultar
        else -> // mostrar
    }
}
```

Otra cosa importante que deberías cambiar es que, independientemente de la opción elijas, la start destination debería ser `fragment_home` y redirigir al `loginFragment` cuando el usuario no esté logeado. Ejemplo en la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional). De esta forma respetas el principio de la [fixed start destination](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) y además aceleras la carga de tu applicación para el caso más frecuente que debería ser cuando el usuario sí está logeado.

### Nueva alternativa

Siguiendo la línea de una única activity, hay una nueva alternativa que sólo mencionaré brevemente para no extender más la respuesta.

No estoy seguro de a que llamas "barra de navegación" (podría ser navigation drawer, navigation rail, bottom navigation o app bar) pero todos esos componentes tienen una implementación [composable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose). La ventaja de usar esta implementación es su flexibilidad infinita que va mucho más allá de simplemente ocultar o mostrar. Gracias a ello es muy sencillo crear por ejemplo, una [composable appBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TopAppBar(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) que tenga diferentes acciones en cada destination o crear animaciones personalizadas como [esta](https://youtu.be/DDd6IOlH3io?t=1074) que no son posibles con una implementación view-based.
Si eliges esta alternativa, probablemente también quieras integrar el nuevo artifact [navigation-compose](https://youtu.be/0z_dwBGQQWQ?t=642) para tener más consistencia.

### Conclusión

Un `NavGraph` es simplemente un array de `NavDestination`s. Tener varios anidados es tecnicamente lo mismo que tener uno solo. No debes pensar que cada graph está asociado a una activity diferente. Los nested graphs existen simplemente para mejor organización y para que puedas reutilizarlos en otro `NavController`. Incluso si eliges la opcion de las dos activities, **no necesitas tener dos graphs**. Separalos sólo si lo crees conveniente.

Comment: Vale, entonces por lo que me dices, cuando yo navego de graph A a graph B, aunque en graph B haya un segundo activity que es el padre, para Android es como si aun siguiera cargando el graph A, ¿correcto? Y otra duda... que sería más conveniente, crearme este segundo activity que he comentado, o meter la barra de navegación en el primer y único activity y ocultarla/mostrarla cuando me convenga?

Comment: Edité la respuesta para corregirla y agregar la nueva alternativa. En realidad si había una opción recomendada. Lamento no haberlo sabido en su momento